# Node-gyp 0.12.0 not found

Tags: node.js

When I attempt to install memwatch from npm with `npm install memwatch` I receive these errors before it fails completely:

```
gyp WARN EACCES user does not have permission to access the dev dir "~/.node-gyp/0.12.0"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/var/folders/bf/_rxhpvq936b1vxf9ylygj86r0000gn/T/.node-gyp"
```

and

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1067:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.3.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/cmlewis95/Dropbox/Programming/Projects/Markdown/node_modules/memwatch
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "memwatch"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! memwatch@0.2.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the memwatch@0.2.2 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
```

When I go to the location which it says it doesn't have access to, the version number listed in the error is not a directory.  I only have a 0.10.13 folder there.  I assumed I just needed to update node-gyp but all of the documentation I found on that did not solve the issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you happened to use Window, make it sure your opening commanding prompt as administrators access. By most chances if you using either Linux or OSX, try add a prefix `sudo` in front of your command,

```
sudo npm install memwatch
```

Comment: Tried that as well and had no success.

Comment: are you sure about those directories are writable. For the time being test as `sudo chmod 777 /directory`